# How to Find the Average Rate of Change (Velocity)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A problem asked this:

> The rocket club wants to model rockets straight up into the air. The height of rocket A can being modeled by the function $y=-16x^2+88x$. The function that models the height of rocket B is shown below.  Compare the functions by finding and interpreting maximums, X – intercepts, and average rates of change over the x–interval $[0,2]$.

How do I find the average rates of change?

Comment: its average speed over time. So take the derivative of the original function. The calculate the speed at x=0 and x=2. Then subtract final velocity from initial velocity and divide it by time which is 2 hours.

Comment: @user60887 I'm not sure about that. I don't know very much physics, but I think that will calculate average *acceleration* where it sounds like the op is looking for average *velocity*. See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vel2.html

Comment: Oops your right I thought he meant acceleration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, [average velocity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vel2.html) is change in position divided by change in time:

$$velocity = \frac{position_2 - position_1}{time_2-time_1}.$$

---

Now, for the problem at hand:

At time $x=0$ the rocket is at height $y = -16(0)^2+88(0) = 0$.

At time $x=2$ the rocket is at height $y = -16(2)^2 + 88(2) = 112$.

...

---

Try to take it from here and let me know if you run into any trouble.